# How can I read in values from a text file and calculate how many times a value repeats and then find the average?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file called text.txt which looks like this:

```
5.H6 7.891 0.3
6.H6 7.693 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
8.H6 7.446 0.3
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
8.H6 7.65014 0.3
10.H6 7.54 0.3
12.H6 8.067 0.3
13.H6 8.047 0.3
14.H6 7.69624 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
17.H8 7.169 0.3
16.H8 8.27957 0.3
18.H6 7.385 0.3
19.H8 7.657 0.3
20.H8 7.78512 0.3
21.H8 8.06057 0.3
```

I want to create a new output text file which looks like this:

```
 Atom nVa  predppm   avgppm    
  7.H2   2   7.674   7.853    
  9.H2   2   7.434   7.458    
  20.H2  2   7.602   7.898   
  21.H2  1   7.959   7.898   
  8.H1'  1   5.363   5.238
```

Essentially I want to read in values from text.txt and see if values in the first column repeat. For example, `5.H6` from `text.txt` repeats in row 1 and 5. The values in the second columns for `5.H6` are 7.891 and 7.72158, I want to calculate the average for them and put them in a column in my output file under `avgppm` in my sample output file. Also, in my second column of my sample output file, called `nVa` I want to count how many times my a value from the first column of `text.txt` is repeated. For example, `5.H6` is repeated twice so the second column should be 2 for `Atom 5.H6`.

Right now, I'm just trying to code to get the first, second and fourth column from my sample output file. But later on I want to add separate columns to my file like `predppm`, `stdev`, `delta`, etc.

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'text.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep = r'/s+', header = None)
df[df.duplicated([' '], keep=False)]
df.sum(axis=1) / len(df.columns)


df.to_csv("output.txt",sep = r'/s+',header=None)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, I can't test my code out because I keep getting errors.

Edit: Error

```
  gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False).agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]}).rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4416, in groupby
**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1699, in groupby
return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 392, in __init__
mutated=self.mutated)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2690, in _get_grouper
raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'Atom'
```

Comment: what would reasonable headers be for your original text file?

Comment: im not sure what you mean. The file doesn't have any headers but if I were to give it some, the first column would be "atom" the second would be "ppm" and the third would be "error"

Comment: Are you looking for `df.describe().T`? If you want exactly what you mentioned, you could do a groupby and then call describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `df` as:

```
     Atom      ppm  unclear
0    5.H6  7.89100      0.3
1    6.H6  7.69300      0.3
2    7.H8  8.16859      0.3
3    8.H6  7.44600      0.3
4    5.H6  7.72158      0.3
5    9.H8  8.10530      0.3
6    8.H6  7.65014      0.3
7   10.H6  7.54000      0.3
8   12.H6  8.06700      0.3
9   13.H6  8.04700      0.3
10  14.H6  7.69624      0.3
11   6.H6  7.70272      0.3
12  17.H8  7.16900      0.3
13  16.H8  8.27957      0.3
14  18.H6  7.38500      0.3
15  19.H8  7.65700      0.3
16  20.H8  7.78512      0.3
17  21.H8  8.06057      0.3
```

Use `groupby()` to collect information per-`Atom`, then apply aggregation functions as desired:

```
gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False)
        .agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]})
        .rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))
gb.head()
     Atom ppm         
          nVa   avgppm
0   10.H6   1  7.54000
1   12.H6   1  8.06700
2   13.H6   1  8.04700
3   14.H6   1  7.69624
4   16.H8   1  8.27957
```

That gives the workflow for grouping and aggregating, but it's not quite in the format you requested.  We can drop the multi-level column structure, although it's not strictly necessary to compute the values you're interested in:

```
gb.columns = gb.columns.droplevel()
gb = gb.rename(columns={"":"Atom"})

     Atom  nVa   avgppm
0   10.H6    1  7.54000
1   12.H6    1  8.06700
2   13.H6    1  8.04700
3   14.H6    1  7.69624
4   16.H8    1  8.27957
5   17.H8    1  7.16900
6   18.H6    1  7.38500
7   19.H8    1  7.65700
8   20.H8    1  7.78512
9   21.H8    1  8.06057
10   5.H6    2  7.80629
11   6.H6    2  7.69786
12   7.H8    1  8.16859
13   8.H6    2  7.54807
14   9.H8    1  8.10530
```

See [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) docs for a full treatment.

Comment: I tried implementing your code and I get this error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ams.py", line 8, in <module>
    gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False).agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]}).rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4416, in groupby
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1699, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
KeyError: 'Atom'

Comment: if the formatting is too bad, I can edit my question to show my exact error

Comment: Are you using `df` as I defined it?  I added column names to your example data.  If not, just use `df.columns = ["Atom", "ppm", "unclear"]` to mimic my setup.

Comment: I used df  = pd.read_csv("text.txt", sep = ' ', header = None). The problem is, I can't use column names to my "text.txt" file, i need to run that text file in another program and it needs to have that format.

Comment: got it, I will try that!

Comment: Thank you, this code worked. However with the code you gave, my output gives the first column with indexes starting from zero, how can I get rid of this so that the first column is "Atom"

Comment: also one final question: if I wanted to add more columns would I create them by adding to this piece of code 
`gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False)
        .agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]})
        .rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))`

Comment: Good!  For the purposes of computation, the index column doesn't really matter.  But if you want to save to file without the index, use `index=False`.  Like this: `gb.to_csv("atom.csv", index=False)`

Comment: re: additional columns, you should really read up on the `groupby` docs i linked to at the end of my answer.  the short answer is yes, but you may want different kinds of aggregation and/or custom aggregation functions.  it's all definitely possible.