# How can I call a function that needs to use values that are from a text file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two functions:

```
errorLim = 0.3

def getQ(x):
    q = math.log(1.0- erf(abs(x)/SQRT2))
    return q

def getQMulti(ppm,errorLim):
    x = (ppm-peakAvg)/errorLim
    q = getQ(x)
    x0=2.0
    q0=getQ(x0)
    QMulti = 1.0+(q/math.abs(q0))
    return QMulti
```

I have a file called `expAtoms` which is like this:

```
3.H5 5.40077
2.H8 7.75894
3.H6 7.60437
3.H5 5.40001
5.H5 5.70502
5.H6 7.96472
""
""
6.H6 7.96178
6.H5 5.71068
```

How can I group the values in the first column and see if they are the same, and if they are then take the average of the values in the second column. For example `3.H5` repeats, so take the average of `5.40077` and `5.40001` and use it as the `peakAvg` in my `getQMulti` program. The average in this example would be 5.40039 and the `ppm` values would be the `5.40077` and `5.40001`

```
import pandas as pd

expAtoms = 'expAtoms.txt'

df2 = pd.read_table(expAtoms,delimiter = " ", header = None)
df2.rename(columns={0:"atom",1:"value"}, inplace=True)
df2.groupby('atom').value.mean()

for atom in df.atom.unique():
    ppm = df.where(df.atom==atom).value.dropna()
    peakAvg = ppm.mean()

getQMulti(ppm,peakAvg,errorLim)
```

Comment: What do the lines with quotes (`""`) represent?

Comment: They don't represent anything, those would be NaN lines that I don't want to use

Comment: Read the file, maybe using the csv module, into a list with each line being an item in the list; sort the list on the first column, use itertools.groupby to produce all the values where the first column is the same; take the average of each groups values and use it.

Comment: How is your question not being answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850757/how-can-i-read-in-values-from-a-text-file-and-calculate-how-many-times-a-value-r)???

Comment: The title of your question doesn't reflect what you are asking.

Comment: Please refrain from spamming the same question. You can add a bounty eventually if your question does not recieve an answer, if you want it to get more attention

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I didn't mean to spam with the same question; I will be more careful next time however I don't see how the two questions are the same because the old question was about finding average, std dev, etc., whereas I'm asking how to implement a specific function now

Comment: @user8290579 you [specifically ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922381/how-can-i-implement-a-function-i-created-that-requires-me-to-read-in-from-a-file) how to implement your `getQMulti` and `getQ` functions using the grouped statistics from your csv file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("path/to/your_file.txt", delimiter=" ", header=None)
df.rename(columns={0: "atom", 1:"value"}, inplace=True)

>>> df
Out[1]:
   atom    value
0  3.H5  5.40077
1  2.H8  7.75894
2  3.H6  7.60437
3  3.H5  5.40001
4  5.H5  5.70502
5  5.H6  7.96472
6   NaN      NaN
7   NaN      NaN
8  6.H6  7.96178
9  6.H5  5.71068

>>> df.groupby('atom').value.mean()
Out[2]:
atom
2.H8    7.75894
3.H5    5.40039
3.H6    7.60437
5.H5    5.70502
5.H6    7.96472
6.H5    5.71068
6.H6    7.96178
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Note that this code expects that your file will contain only the table, without header or anything else.

I you want to extract specific values:

```python
ppm = df.where(df.atom == "3.H5").value.dropna()
peakAvg = ppm.mean()
```

But you should probably change your function to add `peakAvg` as an argument, so you can pass the value to the function.

```python
def getQMulti(ppm, peakAvg, errorLim):
    x = (ppm-peakAvg)/errorLim
    q = getQ(x)
    x0=2.0
    q0=getQ(x0)
    QMulti = 1.0+(q/math.abs(q0))
    return QMulti
```

---

**EDIT:**

In order to apply your function iteratively on all value like that:

```python
for atom in df.atom.unique()  # iterate over all atoms
    ppm = df.where(df.atom == atom).value.dropna()
    peakAvg = ppm.mean()

    # Run your function here
```

But note that your function will have to handle array-like structures, so you'll probably have to implement it using `numpy` instead of `math`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it however I'm getting a syntax error that says:
`SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`
when its talking about `ppm = df.where(df.atom == "3.H5").value.dropna()` and also, how can I run it without specifying `3.H5` for example and just run through all of the values

Comment: So for example, when I call `getQMulti`, it runs through all the atom names (i.e.: `3.H5`) and finds the average for it and uses the two ppm values associated with it (i.e.: 5.40077 and 5.40001) to compute getQMulti

Comment: How do I implement it using numpy instead of math? does numpy have functions like `erf`?

Comment: also I just tried out your code and I'm getting an error like this:
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'atom'` is this the error you were saying i would get because im not implementing my function with numpy?

Comment: @user8290579: numpy should have all functions needed except for `erf` but you'll find a similar function under `scipy.special.erf`, which should work well. About your AttributeError, can you check that the first column of `df` is "atom"? This code works for me, so I'm not sure where the error is from.

Comment: actually, the file that I'm reading in has no header, so I that's why it is saying that "atom" has Attribute Error and "value" has attribute error. Do you know how I can implement your code while accounting for the fact that there is no header in my file?

Comment: I already took account for that, that's what my two first lines are doing: `pd.read_table` has `header=None`, and then I rename the default columns names to "atom" and "value".

Comment: Oh alright, would it be possible for me to edit my code with what I'm implementing so you can see if there is something i am doing wrong?

Comment: never mind I saw my mistake, thanks for all the help! it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can read from files line-by-line in Python with this simple bit:

```
with open('expAtoms.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        # To get each column value, use split()
        left, right = line.split(" ")
```

Keep in mind that this assumes columns are separated by spaces. From there I would save the values in a dictionary, so you can check them in the future when you're looking for rows whose left side values match (There is a lot of room for optimization for this step, but that's a separate issue).

Comment: This would fail on the lines with quotations `""`, so I would add an `if` statement to filter those out